# how to stop spam clicks from send to the datebase? (php)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, spam

I'm trying to do something and when i spam clicking on the text thats sending more than 1 time what i wanted to...
whats the "text button" doing this to send the user to a page, and in this page there is a query to add 1 number to the table in the datebase.

but like a said when i spam clicking on text button before the other page loading, thats will add more than 1 number, and thats not what i want...
how to fix this?

note: my english is not perfect so if i was wrong in something... :D

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear. Can U provide your pho code to understand better your question?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "spam clicking"?

Comment: Spam click : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOji7CISx3w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a timeout on the button that starts when the user first clicks the button. Then on every next click prevent the button click till the end of the timer. (Example uses jQuery javascript library)

```
var buttonClicked = false;

$(#button).on('click', function(e) {
  if( buttonClicked ) {

    // prevent button click and return
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  // set button clicked to true
  buttonClicked = true;

  // reset button clicked after some time
  setTimeout(function() {
    buttonClicked = false;
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Very simple and nice solution.